# How log off from a session in Remote Desktop Connection without having the Windows login windows appearing?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, login, remote-access

I have a kiosk application running on Windows 7 Ultimate, I use Remote Desktop Connection to access the device for maintenance.

As soon as I connect to the kiosk it shows the [Windows login screen](https://www.novell.com/communities/media/img/11748-1.jpg) meanwhile I see the remote desktop.

From my remote machine when I disconnect the kiosk, it still shows up the login window, I need instead display our application as no one can physically enter user/password on the kiosk.

How to do it?

Comment: is it possible for you to just restart the computer after you complete your session? and make sure windows automatically logs in and starts the application?

Comment: yes, I am currently using Autologon for Windows, just wondering if where was an alternative approach. Thanks all guys for your support.

Comment: that's one option, but if you forget to reboot, the kiosk will remain locked. ('tho using RDC, that's about the only option.)

Comment: Try logmein, i have over 40 accounts and it doesn't push the account back to the login page after you've logged out, you can test this. I'm not sure what ricky beam is talking about that it's not a way to remotely connect to a desktop, cause it clearly is. Look at that, 2 options now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways i can think of the fix this problem

After you have updated your kiosk or application, Simply restart the computer after you've finished and force windows 7 to automatically log in the the primary account using these steps.

method 1

1. `Win Key + R` --> `control userpasswords2` OR `netplwiz` --> enter
2. `Uncheck the box that Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`, select the `User Name` that will be automatically logged in, and then click Apply button.
3. In the Start Menu search line, type `shell:startup`, press Enter, Copy the application that needs to start up in this folder.

method 2.

try using an alternative remote desktop application that doesn't push the user to the login screen after you logout. example: logmein.com

Comment: rofl, 1 year later.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 isn't a *terminal server*.  A Remote *Desktop* session is actually connecting you to the desktop.  Only one person at a time can be logged in -- console, or remote.  There's no getting around that with Win7.  You'll need an *actual* server OS, like 2003, etc. and a terminal server license.

[update] for just remote administrator access, the default 2 admin user license works. (and it's what I've used for years.)  Desktop versions don't have a terminal server admin mode.

Comment: how exactly does this answer the question he's asking?

Comment: Remote access will take over the console - period.  If you want to login remotely and interact with it, it's going to lock out the console, and someone will have to log back in *locally*  If an auto-login app tries to log the console back in, it will kick you off the remote session exactly where you were typing.

Comment: so you're saying what he wants to do is not possible, that's not an answer, there are tons of alternatives, for example, using logmein. i personally think my comment would work also, to simply restart the computer.

Comment: All you are basically telling him why its not working, not how to solve the problem, which he already knows it doesn't work.

Comment: By explaining **why it does not work**, and why RDC isn't going to. logmein, vnc, etc. are not *Remote Desktop Connection*.